# What is the difference between 投诉 and 抱怨?

Tags: meaning, difference

is there a difference between 投诉 and 抱怨? All I know is that they both mean "complain".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

投诉=complain (to a department)

抱怨=grumble (usually talking to a friend)

If you look at the character, 诉=suit, 怨=grudge

Answer (score 6):

It's right that they both mean complain, and that is because "complain" has different meanings. 
If you look up complain in a [dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/complain) , 抱怨 is corresponding to the

> 1.To express feelings of pain, dissatisfaction, or resentment.

and 投诉 is corresponding to

> 2.To make a formal accusation or bring a formal charge.

Answer (score 1):

抱怨 is to complain
投诉 is to lodge a complaint

Answer (score 1):

投诉 means to complain in the **legal** or "formal" sense.抱怨 means to complain in the **social** sense.

They both meant to "complain," just in different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

投诉 is to express your discontentment to some organizations or institutes; 抱怨 is usually used to grumble to people around you.